# Writing to a new .txt file with every run

Tags: python

I am reading 100+ files out of a directory and everyday a new one is added. I need to save all the data from previous days as well as the day it is run into a new.txt file every time the program is run. Is there anyway to have the program create the new file, but also put the current date that the program was run into the file name. I do not have any code to for this yet. I was just seeing if there is a built in function for doing something like this.

File name example
AxisMonitorAverages "Date".txt
AxisMonitorAverages "Date".txt

Comment: you could use the datetime module to get the date in whatever format you'd like https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: I would personally use a timestamp, as you will be defining the date with a single integer. Also, within the same module Andrew commented there are a lot of useful functions to change between timestamp and different date formats if you needed to convert them to a human legible format.

Answer (score 0):

Use the datetime library, open a file with date as its name, write content to the file, close the file to save it.

Code attached below, replace `your content here` with necessary data.

```
from datetime import datetime

f = open(f"{datetime.now().date()}.txt", "w+")

f.write("your content here")

f.close()
```